# Rsync file with regex

Tags: regex, unix, rsync

The folder in somehost is as following

```
/strbase/logs/service
```

Which has among many files the following file:

```
service.fix.20151109.log.gz
```

I want to use rsync to transfer this file to my local home directory, but I have to use a regex

```
^service\.fix\.20151109\.log\.gz$
```

This works according to regex101.com.

I tried the following command but nothing got transferred.

```
/usr/local/bin/rsync -a --bwlimit=1333 --include="^service\.fix\.20151109\.log\.gz$" --exclude="*" --rsync-path=/usr/bin/rsync somehostname:/strbase/logs/service ~
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst it does not answer the original question of how to use rsync with a regex, to transfer the file `service.fix.20151109.log.gz` I used:

```
/usr/local/bin/rsync -a --bwlimit=1333 --rsync-path=/usr/bin/rsync somehostname:/strbase/logs/service/service.fix.20151109.log.gz ~
```

I took out the include and exclude.

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

First, your filter specification is wrong, it should be:

```
--include="service.fix.20151109.log.gz"
```

rsync does not use regexes (it uses patterns as described in the man page) and it matches by default from beginning to end of string.

Secondly, `--exclude="*"` is hiding the folder `/service` completely which is the parent folder of the file to be included. It should be `exclude=/strbase/logs/service/*` instead.

---

The final command should look like this:

```
/usr/local/bin/rsync -a --bwlimit=1333 \
   --include="/strbase/logs/service/service.fix.20151109.log.gz" \
   --exclude="*" \
   --rsync-path=/usr/bin/rsync \
   somehostname:/strbase/logs/service ~
```

However, this makes sense for demonstration issues. In real live, I would simply rsync that single file, like this:

```
rsync -a server:/path/to/file ~
```

Comment: im afraid even this does not work, nothing is transferred.

Comment: Why do you pass the `--include` option at all? I'm asking because you don't exclude anything.

Comment: Oh I see. Did you tried to change the order of `--exclude` and `--include` on the command line?

Comment: tried `/usr/local/bin/rsync -a --bwlimit=1333 --exclude="*" --include="service.fix.20151109.log.gz" --rsync-path=/usr/bin/rsync somehost:/strbase/logs/service ~`
still no difference

Comment: I have updated the `--include` to be an absolute path. Now it should work.